# yii FULLTEXT index matching query

Tags: mysql, sql, yii, match, against

I want to creat a sql query in yii framework that look like this:

```
mysql> SELECT id, body, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
-> ('Security implications of running MySQL as root') AS score
-> FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
-> ('Security implications of running MySQL as root');
```

i try this but it's not working:

```
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('data', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'condition' => 'MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Security implications of running MySQL as root') AS score', 
WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Security implications of running MySQL as root')
                'limit' => '20',            ),
            'pagination' => false
        ));
```

Comment: Try model()->findAllBySql("Query")

Answer (score 2):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#condition-detail

> This refers to the WHERE clause in an SQL statement

So there should be only `MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Security implications of running MySQL as root')`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#select-detail

> This refers to the SELECT clause in an SQL statement

Here your place for `id, body, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Security implications of running MySQL as root') AS score`

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to execute the ALTER query for search column.

```
 ALTER TABLE item ADD FULLTEXT(title,description,location);
```

Query to search

```
 $query = \common\models\Item::find()
             ->where(['is_active'=>'1']);
 $query->andWhere("MATCH(title,description,location) AGAINST 
 ('$searchKeywords' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
```